# In Silverlight 4 , how does one add a cancel button to the BusyIndicator control?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I believe you can edit the template for the BusyIndicator, however, I do not have expression blend and I am not familiar with doing this.  Does anyone have sample XAML that I could start with?

*I presume blend just makes it easier to accomplish, but I am unsure how to begin with standard VS.NET.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xaml addresses 2 issues that I had problems with by using the standard sample XAML (posted by Chris) from the Toolkit sources. I have also simplified the XAML to just add a *Cancel* button .

1. Data binding ( see here: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/163280/368692.aspx )
2. Hiding the default progress bar, b/c once you use data template you should use your own progress bar, so you can control positioning

*NOTE: I am using Caliburn Micro for MVVM, and if you're not using MVVM you'll probably just use a normal click event handler for the Cancel button.*

Code sample:

```
<Controls:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding}">
    <Controls:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BusyContent}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Height="15" Margin="2"/>
                <Button cal:Message.Attach="CancelBusyIndicator()" Content="Cancel"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2 2 2 2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    <Controls:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </Controls:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use Expression Blend - you can simply provide the control with a BusyContentTemplate.  The Silverlight Toolkit examples demonstrate this here: http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html.  Copying and pasting a snippet from those examples:

```
<controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" DisplayAfter="0">
    <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                <TextBlock Text="Downloading Email" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock Text="Downloading message 4/10..."/>
                    <ProgressBar Value="40" Height="15"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 2 0"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2 0 0 0"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
</controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

Hope this helps...

Chris

Comment: I just saw this as I d/l Toolkit source. I guess all I am missing with this snippet is event handler for _Cancel_ button, in which I can set IsBusy = false.  Thanks.